# How to transfer/download a zip file from local desktop into putty server(ssh)?

Tags: ssh, zip, putty, file-transfer

I'm trying to transfer my zip file from my local desktop into my putty server and unzip it. So how can I do that?

Actually I'm trying to download the file directly from the website link into my server using wget command but it fails, so I download it down to my desktop then transfer them into the server again but I've no experience on this.

Anyone can give a helping hand here.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux/OSX use `scp filename www.example.com:~/` that will ask you for ssh credentials for example.com and then put file filename into your home folder. On windows you can use winscp, that will have a gui